# How do i combine data values in array to create a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
var players = [{id: 17, amount: 126},
{id: 17, amount: 45},
{id: 12, amount: 44},
{id: 12, amount: 23}];
```

How would i turn the above array into a new array adding the amount for each id.

```
var newArray=[{id:17.amount:171},{id:12,amount:67}];
```

Comment: @AdamAzad You can not see how 126+45=171?

Comment: check out [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: I would use reduce() to make an object and than I would loop over that to make your need array.

Comment: @AdamAzad The sum is group by id, id 17 is 126+45.

Answer (score 4):

You could group the same id with a hash table and add the amount, where necessary.

```js
var players = [{ id: 17, amount: 126 }, { id: 17, amount: 45 }, { id: 12, amount: 44 }, { id: 12, amount: 23 }],
    grouped = players.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            (hash[a.id] = hash[a.id] || r[r.push({ id: a.id, amount: 0 }) - 1]).amount += a.amount;
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Basically this line

```
(hash[a.id] = hash[a.id] || r[r.push({ id: a.id, amount: 0 }) - 1]).amount += a.amount;
```

checks if `hash[a.id]` exists and if not, then this part

```
r[r.push({ id: a.id, amount: 0 }) - 1]
```

is perfomed, which contains of two parts, a part to access the result set and inside it pushes a new objetc set to the result set. While `push` returns the new length of the array, it need to decrease the index to get the last inserted element.

```
r[                                - 1]
  r.push({ id: a.id, amount: 0 })
```

After that, take the property `amount` and increase by the amount of the actual element.

Comment: Why are you using `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}`?

Comment: to prevent some `id` like 'toString' to break the hash table.

Comment: The code seems to work fine with `{}`. You might also want to explain what's going on in here. Even with years of JS experience, this isn't exactly easy to read, not to mention understand.

Comment: in this case where only numbers are keys, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the output format a little, to make it easier to search:

```js
var players = [{ id: 17, amount: 126 }, { id: 17, amount: 45 }, { id: 12, amount: 44 }, { id: 12, amount: 23 }],
    result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
  result[players[i].id] = 
      (result[players[i].id] || 0) + // The existing amount, or 0 for a new `id`
       players[i].amount;           // Add the current amount
}

console.log(result);
console.log('Amount for 17: ' + result[17]);
```

This way, you don't have to filter the result on it's `id` value, to get the amount.

Answer (score 0):

You could push element in a a new array if id is new or just add amount to the previous if it already exists :

```
var players = [{ id: 17, amount: 126 }, { id: 12, amount: 103 }, { id: 17, amount: 45 }, { id: 12, amount: 44 }, { id: 12, amount: 23 }];
var results = [];
results.push(players.sort((a,b) => a.id-b.id)[0]);
var shift = 0;
players.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
   if (index < arr.length - 1){
     if (item.id === arr[index+1].id) {
       results[index + shift].amount += arr[index+1].amount;
       shift--;
     }
     else results.push(players[index+1]);
   }
});
console.log(results); // [ { id: 12, amount: 170 }, { id: 17, amount: 171 } ]
```

Comment: This code doesn't work if the players aren't sorted by `id`.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I've just fixed the bug above. I also changed the set of tests to prove my sort() is efficient to produce expected result.